# How can I know which feature is clicked in a Windows Mobile application?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, hook, global

How can I know which feature (menu items, buttons, etc.) is clicked in a Windows Mobile application?

I need to create an app which listens to user clicks globally, much like what windows global hooks does and I need to know which part/control of every application the user clicked on.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Thw Windows CE OS itself doesn't support mouse hooks at all.  It supports keyboard hooks (unofficially, but it's been there since 1.0).  The only way to get all mouse events is to write a custom touchpanel driver and that is no small feat, especially when you have no information about the hardware.  Maybe if you give us a better idea *why* you need this ability, we can offer alternatives.

Comment: I need to log which feature is clicked/tapped on the device globally. I've done a desktop version using hooks but as you've mentioned, Windows CE doesn't support mouse hooks. Thanks for answering my question. Any suggestions will be appreciated. +1 for you